# nfs4 ACL won't allow group names with spaces

Tags: permissions, rhel, nfsv4

I configure red hat 8.7 to work with active directory and NFS4.1 ACL.

When I am trying to add permissions to folder/file with command:

```shell
nfs4_setfacl -R -a A:g:domain users@test.com:rx imex_home/
```

Do I have a problem with the space? Is it a bug, or did I not write correctly?

Because `users/groups` without space, works.

Comment: Have you tried using `"`'s as appropriate -e.g. maybe `"domain users@test.com"` or `"A:g:domain users@test.com:rx"` or even use a \  like `A:g:domain\ users@test.com:rx`

Comment: tired:  nfs4_setfacl -R -a "A:g:domain\ users@test.com:rx" imex_home/   is stuck

Comment: so you tried a combination of the last two suggestions?